# How to use swift variables in html code?

Tags: html, swift

I try to use swift variables in html code. 
But first of all, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

let webView = WKWebView()

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

var testVar = "test"
var theResult: String = ""


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "someUrl")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300)
 //   webView.sizeToFit()
    webView.load(request)
    view.addSubview(webView)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('username').value='\(usernameTextField.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('password').value='\(passwordTextField.text!)'", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click()", completionHandler: nil)
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('item623')[0]. getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();", completionHandler: nil)

    getValues()

    }

func getValues()
{

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText") { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(result)
            self.theResult = (result as? String) ?? ""
            //self.theResult = result
            print(result)
            print("\(webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('table')", completionHandler: nil))")

        }
    }

    webView.loadHTMLString("""
    <table Border=“1“>
        <caption>
            Vertretungsplan
        </caption>
            <tr>
        <td align=“center“ width=“250px“ length=“100px“>"\(theResult)"</td>
                <td>test1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello World!</td>
                <td>test2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test3</td>
                <td>hello</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    """, baseURL: nil)

}}
```

A part of the html code:

```
<table class=„mon_head“>…</table>
<div class = „mon_title“>4.5.2018 Freitag</div>
<table class="mon_list">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="list"></tr>
    <tr class="odd list">
        <td align="center" class="list">...</td>
        <td align="center" class="list">4</td>
        <td align="center" class="list">Vertretung</td>
        <td align="center" class="list">Mu</td>
        <td align="center" class=„list“>45</td>
        <td class=„list“> </td>
        <td class=„list“> </td>
        <td class=„list" align=„center“>WaS</td>
        <td class=„list" align=„center“> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list even“></tr>
        …
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In the field, in which the variable is, stands "".
If you execute

```
document.getElementsByTagName('table')[1].getElementsByTagName('tr')[1].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerText
```

on the website in the console, then "VIb" will be returned. Its in the tree dots in this line:

```
<td align="center" class="list">...</td>
```

So the problem is that "" and not "VIb" is in the table.
Hope you can help me ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `print` syntax - *(theResult)* - try using String concatenation.

Change this:

```
<td align=“center“ width=“250px“ length=“100px“>"\(theResult)"</td>
```

To this:

```
<td align=“center“ width=“250px“ length=“100px“>" + theResult + "</td>
```

A few more important points:

- In Swift, the "escape" character is `\`. Thus, to add a double quote you should use `<td align=`"center`"`. As you code looks, I'd say it's unpredictable exactly what the value of the HTML string is.
- Try "building" the string piece by piece, a la `var myString = "<td align=`"center`"` then on the next line code in `myString += "width=`"250px`"`, so on and so forth. Add breakpoints and actually *see* what string you are building.

**EDIT:**

Pretty much every I said above is correct. (I *did* say your string value was hard to predict!) Beware, lengthy answer coming - hopefully you'll see what I'm saying.

You want an HTML string, and if you do this:

```
let theResult = "Vlb"
let loadHTMLString = """
    <table Border=“1“>
    <caption>
    Vertretungsplan
    </caption>
    <tr>
    <td align=“center“ width=“250px“ length=“100px“>"\(theResult)"</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Hello World!</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    """
    print(loadHTMLString)
```

The output is this:

```
<table Border=“1“>
<caption>
Vertretungsplan
</caption>
<tr>
<td align=“center“ width=“250px“ length=“100px“>"Vlb"</td>
<td>test1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello World!</td>
<td>test2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test3</td>
<td>hello</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This was my proposal, but using your string variable. It's close, but notice the double quotes around `Vlb`. So maybe your issue *isn't* how you're building your HTML string - maybe `theReturn` really *is* empty.

That said, Here's what you need (and I proposed) for building your HTML string:

```
let loadHTMLString =
        "<table Border=\"1\"<caption>Vertretungsplan</caption>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td align=\"center\" width=\"250px\" length=\"100px\">" + theResult + "</td>" +
                "<td>test1</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>Hello World!</td>" +
                "<td>test2</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<td>test3</td>" +
                "<td>hello</td>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</table>"
```

Now some of this is "syntactic sugar" I guess (the indentations and using the `+` character for separate lines) but the result is this:

```
<table Border="1"<caption>Vertretungsplan</caption><tr><td align="center" width="250px" length="100px">Vlb</td><td>test1</td></tr><tr><td>Hello World!</td><td>test2</td></tr><tr><td>test3</td><td>hello</td></tr></table>
```

Sorry for how it's display in a single line, but it is valid and the HTML you want. :-)

Three things to pay attention to:

- I'm using `+` for string concatenation, including inserting `theResult` into the string.
- I'm using the escape character `\` before every quote I want in the string, eliminating any `"""`.
- A third thing I found in your string (and it's not in mine) is you are using what I believe is called a "closing double-quote", which my keyboard doesn't even have natively.

Again, the actual issue may *not* be that your string isn't displaying `theResult`, but that in fact `theResult` contains a null string. If this is the case, let me know and I'll gladly delete my answer! Either way, good luck.

Comment: But now  "+ theResult +" is in the table

Comment: I'm thinking the actual issue you have is both of what I was saying - using "print" syntax instead of proper Swift String concatenation *and* not using escape character correctly. I'll do a bit of testing in a project and get an update to my answer shortly.

Comment: Hey, I am sorry that I do not answer for two days :/ , I had a lot do. I have tried your code, but now there is nothing in the table field. Moreover, I get "()" by printing loadHtmlString